# How to refer existing database form another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In my `RegisterpageViewController`, I have the following code:

```
class RegisterpageViewController: UIViewController {

    var database: Connection!

    let usersTable = Table("users")
    let id = Expression<Int>("id")
    let fname = Expression<String>("fname")
    let lname = Expression<String>("lname")
    let email = Expression<String>("email")
    let  password = Expression<String>("password")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        do {
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil,create: true )
            let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("users").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
            let database = try Connection(fileUrl.path)
            self.database = database
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

I want to use do some operation in another `UIViewController` over the database. How can I refer it in my new view controller?

Comment: why dont you use the same code over the another viewcontroller or create a singletone DBManager class who manage all the DB related stuffs ?

Comment: Not directly relevant, but try to name your classes in UpperCamelCase.

Comment: @RatulSharker if i use same code in new ViewController , will it access same DB?  i don't know about singletone DBmanager

Comment: As long as the db path is same it will access the same db. But it would be more managable if you want to introduce a singletone class for managing db related tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Use UserDefault to save your database in UserDefault and can access that database in the app anywhere.

Follow this link to check UserDefault: https://learnappmaking.com/userdefaults-swift-setting-getting-data-how-to/